# Rails routing aliasing and namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a simple namespaced route

```
  map.namespace :api do |api|
    api.resources :genres
  end
```

how can I reuse this block but with another namespace?

Currently I'm achieving that by writing another routes hacked on the fly

```
  map.with_options :name_prefix => 'mobile_', :path_prefix => 'mobile' do |mobile|
    mobile.resources :genres, :controller => 'api/genres'
  end
```

But it seems less than ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  You want "api/genres" to go to the same controller is "mobile_genres", but are trying to find a better way to define the routes than you currently have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the , :controller => 'api/genres' option is your only approach. Only cleanup I can see is: map.namespace :mobile.